# Expected value for choosing number twice

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

I have a problem:

I can choose twice randomly numbers from 1 to 3 and probabilities to choose each numbers can be adjusted for best end result. Choosing a number is independent. But not equally likely. I can define probability for each number.

If I choose twice same number I get 0 points otherwise I get sum of two choosen numbers.
How to calculate best, optimal probability for each number to get max possible sum?
And how to calculate expected value after choosing twice?

I tried like this:
 - Choosing numbers twice from 1 to 3 is actually getting me sum of 2 to 6
 - so I got sum matrix:
       \begin{matrix}
        0 & 3 & 4 \\
        3 & 0 & 5 \\
        4 & 5 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}

I think then it would be probabilities for numbers that represent sum like 
for 3,4 and 5 probability is 2/9, but that looks awfuly wrong.

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts in 
this and future posts. Formatting tips 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What do you mean by the _best, optimal probability for each number to get max possible sum_?

Comment: probablyme Sorry for posting badly formatted and without my toughts / tries, will try to do better in next posts.
@JendrikStelzner best in way that I get highest possible expected value, but so I don't get high probability of getting same number twice coz then I get 0 as end result.

Answer (score 0):

If choosing a number is independent and equally likely, then if $S$ is the number of points you get, then using your table, the distribution of $S$ is
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
s&0&3&4&5\\\hline
P(S=s)&\frac{3}{9}&\frac{2}{9}&\frac{2}{9}&\frac{2}{9}
\end{array}
So, to calculate the expectation of $S$, we have
$$E[S] = 0(3/9)+3(2/9)+4(2/9)+5(2/9)=\frac{8}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks for help! Choosing a number is independent. But not equally likely, I can adjust that some numbers are less likely and some more likely. So I can define my probabilities of how often each number will be choosen. That bothers me, as I don't know what distribution of probabilities should I use. Obviously highest number will have higher probability to be choosen, 2nd highest a little less, and the rest either 0 or something low. But I can't figure out logic how to choose these probabilities.

Comment: @Cazper You should include in your post that the numbers are not equally likely that **you** are defining the distribution on the numbers $\{1,2,3\}$. At least, that's what it sounds like you are saying.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I added clarification to problem. Ty!